# How can I login to lightdm with password for fingerprint-enabled user after 12.10 upgrade?

Tags: login, lightdm, fingerprint-reader

Sorry for the long question.

I have a laptop with ubuntu quantal 12.10, a fingerprint scanner, and a few active user accounts.  When the machine boots up to lightdm, I get a prompt toenter my password or scan my finger print.  Every now and then, fingerprint scanning just doesn't seem to work.  Before the 12.10 upgrade, I was always able to enter my password for this user when fingerprint failed.  Now, no matter what, I have to scan my prints to login as this user.  If I try to login as a different user (fingerprint is not enabled for any others), I can see the password is typed out -- asterisks show in the password input box as I type them -- and get in.  Not so for the fingerprint user.  Any clues on how to figure out what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug you've described seems to have been solved in LightDM shipped with Ubuntu 13.04.

In Ubuntu 12.10 I had the same problem but for a different reason. I had an encrypted home dir and `fingerprint-gui` doesn't store passwords to accounts but instead provides a `pam` module and only checks for a matching fingerprint to allow users to log in. However, to decrypt a home dir one must enter a password, otherwise encryption simply wouldn't make sense. Thus, as long as `ecryptfs` doesn't provide a way to use fingerprints instead of passwords, this system won't work.

Combined with the bug you've described this leads for me to the situation where I have to always first scan my fingerprint for it to fail and only then I'm able to enter a password in `LightDM`.

As a workaround, I've disabled fingerprint authentication for `LightDM` altogether, after all one has to pass this login quite seldom.

This works as follows:

1. Make a copy of the file `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, name it whatever you want. For simplicity, I will assume that you named it `common-auth-pass-only`:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/pam.d/common-auth /etc/pam.d/common-auth-pass-only
   ```
2. Edit the newly created file for example with the command `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth-pass-only`, you will have to remove the line:

   ```
   auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_fingerprint-gui.so try_first_identified debug
   ```

   The exact contents of this line may differ slightly, but the part with `pam_fingerprint-gui.so` will be there.
3. Edit the `lightdm` pam config file for example with the command `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/lightdm`. Replace the file name `common-auth` in the line

   ```
   @include common-auth
   ```

   with the name of the newly created file, the line should then look like this:

   ```
   @include common-auth-pass-only
   ```

**Remember, this is only a temporary workaround, the command `pam-auth-update` won't manage your config for `LightDM` any more after these changes were applied.**